# Meteor / JS: How to do a callback before doing another callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, graphicsmagick

This is a function for manipulating some images via `graphicsmagick` in my meteor application.

If the image is being cropped, I want to check if its width is >900px. Then it should be resized to 900px.

This complete function is not working, as the callback of `gmread.size()` has to be finished before doing the `return gmread.stream` - which is currently not the case. But I don't know how to get this synchron/asynchron thing working...

```
function imageManipulation(inputId, method) {
    var inStream = Files.findOneStream({ _id: inputId }),
        gmread;

    // do some image manipulation depending on given `method`
    if (method == 'crop') {
        gmread = gm(inStream);

        // check if image width > 900px, then do resize
        gmread.size(function(err, size) {
            if (size.width > 900) {
                gmread = gmread.resize('900');
            }
        });
    }

    return gmread.stream('jpg', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
        if (!err) {
            var outStream = Files.upsertStream({ _id: outputFileId }, {}, function(err, file) {
                if (err) { console.warn("" + err); } 
                return;
            });
            return stdout.pipe(outStream);
        }
    }));

});
```

**Update**

I tried to use `meteorhacks:async`, but I do get the error `Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'size'`.

```
function imageManipulation(inputId, method) {
    var inStream = Files.findOneStream({ _id: inputId }),
        gmread;

    if (method == 'crop') {
        gmread = gm(inStream);

        // Asnyc doesn't work
        gmread = Async.runSync(function(done) {
            gmread.size(function(err, size) {
                if (size.width > 900) {
                    gmread = gmread.resize('900');
                }
                done(null, gmread);
            });
        });
    }

    return gmread.stream('jpg', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
        if (!err) {
            var outStream = Files.upsertStream({ _id: outputFileId }, {}, function(err, file) {
                if (err) { console.warn("" + err); } 
                return;
            });
            return stdout.pipe(outStream);
        }
    }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `meteorhacks:async` that pause the execution until you invoke done() callback as shown below.

```
function imageManipulation(inputId, method) {
    var inStream = Files.findOneStream({ _id: inputId }),
        gmread;

    // do some image manipulation depending on given `method`
    if (method == 'crop') {
        gmread = gm(inStream);

        // check if image width > 900px, then do resize
        gmread.size(function(err, size) {
            if (size.width > 900) {
                gmread = gmread.resize('900');
            }
        });
    }

    var response = Async.runSync(function(done) {

      gmread.stream('jpg', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
        if (!err) {
            var outStream = Files.upsertStream({ _id: outputFileId }, {}, function(err, file) {
                if (err) { console.warn("" + err); } 
                return;
            });
            done(null, stdout.pipe(outStream));
          }
        }));
     });
     return response.result
    });
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it correctly, but I'm waiting for the result of `gored.size` to go further to the stream-function. You did it the other way round...?!